how create new column or update column inside a dataframe?
Good morning eveyone
I have a question today, that i don't know exactly how to do.
Having a dataframe, i need create columns dynamically, and those column will contein a set of validations that i have to do, like: validate number os characters, see if there is strange characters inside a description field (break lines for example) , etc.
Having the next list:
raw/ingest_date=20240918/eventos/
raw/ingest_date=20240918/llamadas/
raw/ingest_date=20240918/campanhas/
raw/ingest_date=20240918/miembros/
raw/ingest_date=20240918/objetivos/

i have this dataframe using:
data_T =[(folder, folder.split('/')[-2]) for folder in subfolders]
df_result = spark.createDataFrame(data_T , ["s3_prefix", "table_name"])

output:
s3_prefix                            | table_name
------------------------------------------------------
raw/ingest_date=20240918/eventos/    | eventos
raw/ingest_date=20240918/llamadas/   | llamadas
raw/ingest_date=20240918/campanhas/  | campanhas
raw/ingest_date=20240918/miembros/   | miembros

Now I will do a loop over this dataframe look into each s3_prefix to get information about the parquet files that are stored inside.
for elem in df_result.collect():
    s3_path = f"s3://{bucket_name}/{elem['s3_prefix']}/*.parquet"
    ing_df = spark.read.parquet(s3_path)
    
    ing_df = ing_df.select(F.length('ID').alias('length_ID'))

    ing_df.show(1)

output
eventos
+---------+
|length_ID|
+---------+
|       17|
+---------+
only showing top 1 row

------------------------------
llamadas
+---------+
|length_ID|
+---------+
|       18|
+---------+
...
...
...

And is inside this "for" where i will set my validations and per each validation there must be a column that will contain the result per row, like:
s3_prefix                            | table_name   | id_length |  strange_character  | id_strange character        |
-------------------------------------|--------------|-----------|---------------------|-----------------------------|
raw/ingest_date=20240918/eventos/    | eventos      |   17      |        YES          | [idxxxxxxx3,idxxxxx23]      |
raw/ingest_date=20240918/llamadas/   | llamadas     |   18      |        NO           |                             |
raw/ingest_date=20240918/campanhas/  | campanhas    |   20      |        NO           |                             |
raw/ingest_date=20240918/miembros/   | miembros     |   30      |        YES          | [idxxxsssxs10,idxsdas2200]  |

Can somebody help me to create this new dataframe and how i could use regex to look into description field if there is break line inside the field.
Thank you so much
Regards

Why are you creating df_result Dataframe from Python array only to collect it to the driver? Unless it has large number of elements, you get only overhead as all the parquet reads are again scheduled on the driver

Put s3_path into ing_df as column, join ing_df with df_result by s3_prefix column. Add all those ing_df into a Python array, union them all into one df if you need to
